# Quarkus Dev Services forces quarkus.hibernate-orm.mddestinationdb.database.generation=drop-and-create although I use Flyway

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, flyway

## Background

I use Quarkus service Dev Services to start a Postgres DB in `test` and `dev` profile. The DB schemas are managed using flyway.

## Problem

When using the Dev Services Quarkus sets `quarkus.hibernate-orm.mddestinationdb.database.generation=drop-and-create` which generates the DB according to the entities defined in the project. However, the Flyway scripts define them in a different way, e.g., they add a column which is not present in the entity definition. Hibernate simply drops the column. This is not what I want. I want Hibernate to leave the DB alone even in Dev Services mode.

```
[io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.deployment.HibernateOrmProcessor] (build-8) Setting quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create to initialize Dev Services managed database
```

## What I have tried so far

I have tried to set the property to false explicitly

```
# this is set so I would expect Hibernate to leave the DB as is
%dev.quarkus.flyway.schemas=my_schema
%dev.quarkus.datasource.devservices.port=5434
%dev.quarkus.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
%dev.quarkus.flyway..migrate-at-start=true


# setting this explicitly doesn't turn it of for Dev Services
%dev.quarkus.hibernate-orm.mddestinationdb.database.generation=none
```

## Question

How can I set Quarkus to only use Flyway for setting up the DB in the `dev` and `test` profiles when using Dev Services?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question because database migrations is not meant to be merely used in dev and test dbs but is a feature developed in order to migrate production data. If you really want hibernate to leave your Databases alone in Dev and Test environment you could try to play with `quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation` and set to it none in those environments.